# A closed plane curve $\gamma$ with positive non-constant curvature $\kappa(s)>0$ and rotation index $1$. Does it implies $\gamma$ is simple?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

A closed regular plane curve $\gamma$ with positive non-constant curvature $\kappa(s)>0$ and rotation index (turning number) $1$. Does it implies $\gamma$ is simple?
Note that rotation index is computed as total curvature divided by $2\pi$.

> This seems to me intuitive clear. But I cannot prove it. Can anyone help me to handle this?

Comment: If the curve intersects itself, it then is naturally divided into two closed curves (likely with corners). So what will the rotation index be?